# Get item clicked in horizontal list view created with scroll view

Tags: listview, titanium, titanium-alloy, horizontalscrollview

I create a horizontal listview by scrollview, but I don't know how to add item click event to it and tracking which item is clicked

```
<ScrollView id="scrollView"  showHorizontalScrollIndicator="true" height="20%" width="80%">
    <View id="containerView" backgroundColor="#336699" height="300" width="1000" layout='horizontal' />
</ScrollView>


var columns = [];
for(var index=0;index<15;index++){
    columns[index] = Ti.UI.createView({
        width   : 200,
        height  : 200,
        backgroundColor : '#123456',
        left    : 20 
    });
    $.containerView.add(columns[index]);
}


function doClick(item){
    console.log(item);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding click listener to each view, you can add listener to parent view. And access the other child view by custom id.
For example in your case use the below code.

```
    <ScrollView id="scrollView"  showHorizontalScrollIndicator="true" height="20%" width="80%">
                <View id="containerView" onClick="onContainerViewClicked" backgroundColor="#336699" height="300" width="1000" layout='horizontal' />
    </ScrollView>

    var columns = [];
    for(var index=0;index<15;index++){
       columns[index] = Ti.UI.createView({
           width   : 200,
           height  : 200,
           backgroundColor : '#123456',
           left    : 20,
           id :index 
       });
       $.containerView.add(columns[index]);
    }
    $.containerView.width = 220 * 15;

    function onContainerViewClicked(e){
       alert(e.source.id);
       alert(columns[e.source.id]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give each of your `columns[index]` views a [clickListener](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Event_Handling). This should be executed in your for-loop.

```
columns[index] = Ti.UI.createView({
    width   : 200,
    height  : 200,
    backgroundColor : '#123456',
    left    : 20 
});

columns[index].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // code here is run when the event is fired
    // properties of the event object 'e' describe the event and object that received it
    Ti.API.info('The '+e.type+' event happened');
});

$.containerView.add(columns[index]);
```

There is no need to have an extra function doClick(Item) because you can define it inline.